# Download multiple files from specific "subdirectory", AWS S3 with boto3 & Python 3.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
import os 

client = boto3.client('connect')

s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)

   
for my_bucket_object in s3.Bucket("my_bucket").objects.filter(Prefix="user/folder/"):
    s3.Object(my_bucket_object.bucket_name, my_bucket_object.key).download_file(f'./aws/{my_bucket_object.key}')
```

1. Without iteration, but similar code, I can successfully download individual files.
2. Without downloading, printing the bucket keys shows normal outputs

However, when I iterate over multiple files, and use the key as input for download_file, I get the following error message.  Target key's name seems to be changing?

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> './aws/user/folder\.7g4DBa9A'

I have the following two questions:

1. How can I prevent this from happening and download the files?
2. Is there a way to separate file names from "subdirectories" (I realize AWS doesn't use those, but keys contain directory/file-like names separated only by "/", I would like to separate those for saving purposes)

===========================================================================
Found the answer thanks to Marcin's comment.
After iteratively printing all the outputs, it seemed the first one was the "folder", which translated to strange names when downloading.

ie. 

user/folder/

user/folder/file1

user/folder/file2

etc.

Thus, ignoring that first iteration was able to solve it.

```
for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
       
    output_file = obj.key.split('/')[-1]

    if output_file == "":
        continue
    else:
        s3.Object(bucket_name=my_bucket.name, key=my_bucket_object.key).download_file(arbitrary output path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to separate file names from "subdirectories"

You can split the key by `/` and take the last element before you do `download_file`:

```
output_file = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]
s3.Object(my_bucket_object.bucket_name, my_bucket_object.key).download_file(f'./aws/output_file')
```

Comment: Thank you! Question 2 was answers.  I am still stuck on Question 1 though (for anyone else who views this thread)

Comment: @Shaner You prevent it by having correct save path, which is question 2.

Comment: I found the answer indirectly through your first comment. Thanks!